# How to globally add a custom locator to Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I wrote a custom locator for Protractor that finds `anchor` elements by their `ui-sref` value. In my specs I just used `by.addLocator` to add the custom locator, but I figured this might be a cool thing to publish and have other people use it.

The goal is to add this custom locator to the global Protractor object so it can be used in any of your specs.

My initial approach was to add this functionality in the `onPrepare` block of the Protractor config. Something like the pseudocode below:

```js
onPrepare: function () {
  require('ui-sref-locator')(protractor); // The protractor object is available here.
}
```

That require statement would just execute this function:

```js
function (ptorInstance) {
  ptorInstance.by.addLocator('uiSref', function (toState, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;
    var possibleAnchors = using.querySelectorAll('a[ui-sref="' + toState +'"]');
    var result = undefined;

    if (possibleAnchors.length === 0) {
      result = null;
    } else if (possibleAnchors.length === 1) {
      result = possibleAnchors[0];
    } else {
      result = possibleAnchors;
    }

    return result;
  });
};
```

The problem is that `by` is not defined on the `protractor` object available in the `onPrepare` block. This means that I cannot use the `.addLocator` method.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
function () {
  by.addLocator('uiSref', function (toState, opt_parentElement) {
  ...
```

By should be in the global scope.

Comment: Nope. Protractor is initialized. The function I was looking for is a non-enumerable property (I believe), and that's why I couldn't see it at first glance. I am still understanding some details about my working solution, but when I'm done I'll write up a proper answer.

Comment: You are right. I just checked some older code I wrote that adds a locator inside onPrepare(). Check the updated code.

Answer (score 4):

The `protractor` object passed to the `onPrepare` block has a `By` property. That `By` property has an inherited enumerable property named `addLocator`. My understanding of JavaScript is pretty shallow so it really threw me off that when I `console.log`'ed the `protractor.By` it returned `{}`, but if I did `for (var propName in protractor.By)` it would show me all the "hidden" properties. I'm still struggling to understand that bit.

Working code:

```
onPrepare: function () {
  require('ui-sref-locator')(protractor); // The protractor object is available here.
}
```

The require would execute the function below:

```
function (ptor) {
  ptor.By.addLocator('linkUiSref', function (toState, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;
    var possibleAnchors = using.querySelectorAll('a[ui-sref="' + toState +'"]');
    var result = undefined;

    if (possibleAnchors.length === 0) {
      result = null;
    } else if (possibleAnchors.length === 1) {
      result = possibleAnchors[0];
    } else {
      result = possibleAnchors;
    }

    return result;
  });
};
```

Comment: How can we call this function from seprate JS,where we need to keep it to call inside configuration