# Protractor: How I can extend protractor library?

Tags: angularjs, testing, frameworks, protractor, extension-methods

I want extend the standard protractors methods and create my own library (or something like that), where I can define my own methods and after that using them in testing.

For example: create method `by.MyAttribute('attributeName')` and use it as global method.

Maybe somebody know how can I do this?

Comment: If you want to make it a standalone library, you can take a look at [docs for creating plugins for Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/plugins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make something globally available in `protractor`, use `global` inside `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    global.myvariable = "Hello, world!";
},
```

You should though use global variables wisely - they can pollute namespaces and make your code harder to debug. Alternatively, use `require()` to import your library into the scope of a test.

---

Note that, if you are writing your own locators, you should use [`by.addLocator()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator), see:

- [How to globally add a custom locator to Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458975/how-to-globally-add-a-custom-locator-to-protractor)