# Protractor: How do I create a function that receives an HTML element as a parameter?

Tags: protractor

I'm new to Protractor.

I'm trying to select a button based on the button title. I want to make this into a function, and pass the button title in as a parameter.

This is the hard-coded version which works:

```
    it('I click on a button based on the button title', async function() {
        let button = element(by.css('button[title=example_button_title]'));
        await button.click();
    });
```

I created a global variable and a function to try and replace this, where 'buttonTitle' is the parameter I'm passing into the function:

*Variable:*

```
    let dynamicButton = buttonTitle => { return element(by.css("'button[title=" + buttonTitle + "]'")) };
```

*Function:*

```
    this.selectDynamicButton = async function(buttonTitle) {
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await dynamicButton(buttonTitle).click();
    };
```

When I try this I get the following error:

> Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Apologies if there appear to be basic errors here, I am still learning. I appreciate any help that anyone can give me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom locator using protractors [addLocator](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator) functionality. (this is actually a very similar use case to the example listed in the link)

This would look like the following:

```
onPrepare: function () {

    by.addLocator('buttonTitle', function (titleText, opt_parentElement) {
        // This function will be serialized as a string and will execute in the
        // browser. The first argument is the text for the button. The second
        // argument is the parent element, if any.
        const using = opt_parentElement || document;
        const matchingButtons = using.querySelectorAll(`button[title="${titleText}"]`);
        let result = undefined;

        if (matchingButtons.length === 0) {
            result = null;
        } else if (matchingButtons.length === 1) {
            result = matchingButtons[0];
        } else {
            result = matchingButtons;
        }

        return result;
    });
}
```

This is called like

```
const firstMatchingButton = element(by.buttonTitle('example_button_title'));
const allMatchingButtons = element.all(by.buttonTitle('example_button_title'));
```

I had to edit this code before posting so let me know if this does not work. My work here is largely based off [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24524072/10836734)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to make two smalls tweaks:
1. Remove the onPrepare: function () part and just declared it at the top of my spec file. I'm not sure in which file I need to put the onPrepare part for it to work, so I may need to do some more research.
2. I called it using the example from the Protractor documentation for locators:
element(by.buttonTitle('button_title_example')).click();

Making these changes got my tests to work. Again, many thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped! For the record the onPrepare goes into the conf.js file and it you put it there you will be able to call that locator any any other file in your project. You can see examples of what you can set in the conf [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) and this will really worth reading! I referenced it all the time when I was getting started with Protractor

Comment: That's great. I'll give it a go putting in the conf.js file. I'll also have a proper read through the link you provided. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dynamicButton = buttonTitle => { return element(by.css('button[title=${buttonTitle} ]')) };
```

Use template literals instead of string concatenation with +.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This gave me half the solution I needed to figure out my issue. After looking into template literals (https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-template-literals/), I found that I also needed to replace my single quotation marks with backticks to get it working:
let dynamicButton = buttonTitle => { return element(by.css(`button[title=${buttonTitle} ]`)) };
Making this change caused my tests to start working. Thank you very much for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor already has a built in locator which allows you to get a button using the text. I think you are looking at something like that. See the `element(by.buttonText('text of button'))` locator.

For more reference see [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have an unusual case where the button text of all the buttons is the same, but the tooltip of each is unique, so I think I'll have to try the custom locator suggestion above.

Comment: You can get multiple elements using this locator and save them in an array or list and then pick the element from there using indexes. If you can give me an example, or HTML snippet, I can try to come up with a solution.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the other two suggestions both helped solve my case, but I wanted to provide an HTML snippet in case you have another suggestion that you think would work (the more you know!). Here is the snippet:

<button class="child" id="but11777142" type="button" as="action_1493467" pageobjectelementid="-28" title="TC0001">View</button>